# Использование jQuery в django 1.9

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь разобраться с оценкой товаров, нашел готовое решение хотел попробовать, но что-то никак не получается запустить https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty

Хочу сделать звездочки для оценки товара, что статей не нашел никаких...то, что нашел все на jQuery. Если есть какие ссылки почитать кидайте почитаю.

Мой шаблон, что у меня не так?

```
<div>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/rateit.js-master/scripts/jquery.rateit.js' %}"></script>



    <div id="star"></div>
    <script> $('#star').raty()</script>

</div>
```

поправил script, установил django-jquery через pip добавил в apps, но что-то все равно не работает, что я еще упустил?

Comment: Ну как минимум вы забыли подключить сам jQuery и обращаетесь к `star`, когда его ещё не существует

Comment: Да и вообще rateit дважды зачем-то подключается

Comment: Теперь просто jQuery не подключен

Comment: Да как его подключить?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   ??????

Comment: Я же в apps добавил 'jquery'?

Comment: А вот теперь сходите почитайте где-нибудь в гугле про основы javascript и про способы его подключения к веб-странице, ибо без этого дело дальше не пойдёт